# Discord collector reaction filter way to set a max limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm doing a command to translate every messages that have a certain reaction to the language of the flag emoji (the one that the user reacted with).

But I want the bot to only translate once for one language (if there's two users that react with the us flag, it will translate the message to English only once).

I can use the reaction filter, but in my case for a better code, I'm using a switch statement, so if I use the max property in the reaction filter, I wouldn't be able to translate multiple times a message (only once).

Here's my code :

```js
bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
  const reactionFilter = (reaction, user) => {
    return msg.author.id !== '724682218454253588';
  };
  collector = msg.createReactionCollector(reactionFilter);

  collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
    switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
      case '':
        TranslateMessage(msg, 'fr');
        break;
      case '':
        TranslateMessage(msg, 'en');
        break;
      case '':
        TranslateMessage(msg, 'de');
        break;
      case '':
        TranslateMessage(msg, 'es');
        break;
      case '':
        TranslateMessage(msg, 'ja');
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

(I have a lot more of langues than that in this switch statement, but for the question it's easier to read)

And here's the TranslateMessage function :

```js
async function TranslateMessage(msg, lang) {
  try {
    const traduction = await traduire(msg.content, lang);
    const MessEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(msg.author.username, msg.author.avatarURL)
      .setDescription(traduction);

    return msg.channel.send(MessEmbed);
  } catch (error) {
    return msg.channel.send("There's an error, try again !");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [`reaction.count`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=count) that returns the number of people that have given the same reaction. If it's larger than `1`, you don't need to translate the message to that language.

```js
collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.count > 1) return; // there is already a translation for this reaction
  
  switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
    case '':
      TranslateMessage(msg, 'fr');
      break;
    case '':
      TranslateMessage(msg, 'en');
      break;
    case '':
      TranslateMessage(msg, 'de');
      break;
    case '':
      TranslateMessage(msg, 'es');
      break;
    case '':
      TranslateMessage(msg, 'ja');
      break;
  }
});
```

If you want to avoid sending a new translation when a user removes the last reaction (meaning `reaction.count` will be zero again) and then adds it again, you can use the [`messageReactionRemove`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionRemove) event. It's emitted whenever a reaction is removed, so you can check if the `reaction.count` is dropped to zero, and react as a bot with the same emoji. Of course it would also trigger a translation, so you'll need to filter out bot's reaction:

```js
bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
  const reactionFilter = () => {
    return msg.author.id !== '724682218454253588';
  };
  const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(reactionFilter);

  collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.count > 1 || user.bot) return;

    switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
      case '':
        TranslateMessage(msg, 'fr');
        break;
      case '':
        TranslateMessage(msg, 'en');
        break;
      case '':
        TranslateMessage(msg, 'de');
        break;
      case '':
        TranslateMessage(msg, 'es');
        break;
      case '':
        TranslateMessage(msg, 'ja');
        break;
    }
  });
});

bot.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction) => {
  if (reaction.count === 0)
    reaction.message.react(reaction.emoji);
});
```

Comment: That's a simple solution, I don't know why I didn't think about it. But there's a slight issue (no big deal), is, if the user who reacted first remove his reaction and then add again, it will translate a second time. But that should be good for now, thanks !

Comment: You're welcome. I've just updated my answer with a solution to this. Hopefully :)

Comment: Thanks ! Works perfectly :)